# How to identify the amount of duplicate objects within an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an inventory class that has an array of the class 'Item', called items. Within the Item class, I have an int called quantity to represent how many of the item that you get with each pickup. I haven't been able to figure out how to get the number of duplicate items within the array, so that I can multiply that by the getQuantity() method for that item and get the total quantity of the item that the player is carrying.

```
public class Inventory {


    private Item[] items;   //A private Item array, called items
    private int firstFree;
    private int quantity;
    private WorldRenderer world;


    /**
     * CREATES THE INVENTORY AT A SIZE SPECIFIED IN THE PARATHENESIS
     */
    public Inventory(int size) {
        items = new Item[size];
        firstFree = 0;
    }


    public int getItemCount() {
        for (int i = firstFree; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] != null) {
                return items.length;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean add(Item item) {
        if (firstFree == items.length) {
            return false;
        }
        items[firstFree] = item;

        for (int i = firstFree; i < items.length; i++)
            if (items[i] == null) {
                firstFree = i;
                return true;
            }
        firstFree = items.length;

        return true;


        /**for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
         if (items[i] == null){
         items[i] = item;
         System.out.println("Item " + item.getName() + " added to inventory at index " + i);  // TESTING 
         return true;
         }
         return false;
         }**/
    }

    public Item get(int index) {
        return items[index];
    }

    public void setQuantity(Item item, int quantity) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] == item) {
                items[i].setQuantity(quantity);
            }
        }
    }

    public void removeQuantity(Item item, int quantity) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] == item) {
                items[i].setQuantity(item.getQuantity() - quantity);
            }
        }

    }

    public int getQuantity(Item item) {
        int quantity = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i] == item) {
                quantity = items[i].getQuantity();
            }
        }
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

Perhaps there is a better way to go about creating an inventory for my particular problem?

EDIT: 
Trying the HashMap and getting an NPE at this line

```
     if (items.containsKey(item)){
        Integer previousQuantity = items.get(items);
        items.put(item,  ++previousQuantity); // NPE this line.
    } else {
        items.put(item,  1);
    }
```

Comment: Does changing your code to `quantity += items[i].getQuantity();` produce the expected result? If not, what is the expected result and what result are you currently getting?

Comment: How do you know if an `Item` is a duplicate? You don't seem to have any fields in place (such as a string with the name of the `Item`) that could make that determination.

Comment: You may find it useful to verbalise the problem in non-code first. Then convert that into pseudo code. Doing so might help you understand the logic required to a,choice your goal. In the meantime some thoughts: What makes an Item a duplicate? Your setQuantity and removeQuantity methods are testing if it is the same instance, is that correct? Your getItemCount will return the total array size or 0 only

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses guys, I'm not where I can get into Eclipse right now, at work :(. @musical_coder I have a string 'name' within my GameObject class, which is what my Item class extends. I've tried to find the amount by using .equalsIgnoringCase but I'm probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @Tanis.7x will try that also, and you're too Romski

Comment: @Romski An item is a duplicate if it is the same class, In my game world I drop 2 of the item (a class that extends Item), I have an int quantity in the Item class, so my extended class has that parameter. I want to see when I pick up one of an item, the quantity for that item * 1, if I pick up another then item quantity * 2, etc.

Comment: What does your Item class look like?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than `Item[] items` you might consider `HashMap<Item, Integer> items` where the Integer refers to quantity.

This would make sure that there are no duplicate Items as well as simplify finding the quantity.

**Example:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Inventory {

    private HashMap<Item, Integer> items;
    private int maxSize;

    public Inventory(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        items = new HashMap<Item, Integer>();
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Item item: items.keySet()){
            count += items.get(item);
        }
        return count;
    }

    public boolean add(Item item) {
        if (items.size() >= maxSize){
            return false;
        }

        if (items.containsKey(item)){
            Integer previousQuantity = items.get(items);
            items.put(item,  ++previousQuantity);
        } else {
            items.put(item,  1);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Generic Implementation of equals() and hashCode():**

```
public class Item {
    int itemType;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) { return true; }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) { return false;  }

        Item item = (Item) o;
        if (itemType != item.itemType) { return false; }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return itemType;
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that your Item class hash a functional `equals()` method.

Comment: thanks for the info, I think that I'd like to try this, seems it would simplify things quite a bit. But what do you mean by my Item class having a functional equals() method. I have an int called Type within GameObject (Item extends GO), so I can create Item 'types', will that work?

Comment: The [get method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) on HashMap uses [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for retrieving the Item. You will also need to override the `hashCode()` method. You might want to read up on java hashcode and equals methods.

Comment: @AspiretoCode Basically, if you don't override the equals method, you might end up with duplicates Items in your items list.

Comment: As I was reading your question @AspiretoCode I was thinking HashMap the whole time. I'm glad someone else suggested it, it's the right way to do this. It will also make item lookup much more straightforward and fast.

Comment: @MikeRylander when I go to pickup the second of the same object, this crashes with a null pointer exception? I've put shown the line in the original question.

Comment: @AspiretoCode I would guess that 'previousQuantity' is null for some reason. You might want to try using a debugger to look at the code as it is running.

Comment: @MikeRylander Yes, it's the previousQuantity returning null and I can't seem to figure out why. Is there a more simplistic way to do this, like when I pick up another of the same item, it just adds to the quantity of the original? I think that the Hashmap is a little over my head still.

Comment: @AspiretoCode The "add" method is the only thing that should be putting items into the HashMap and it should initialize the quantity to 1. The Item that you are adding that is giving you trouble is not being inserted into the HashMap correctly when it is first added. You want to find where it is first being put into the map and make sure that the quantity set correctly "`items.put(item,  1);`"

Answer (score 0):

you can find out number of unique item by using Set. In Set no item is repeated. So if you can convert your array to set then you can find the number of unique item. And you can get the number of repeated item by subtracting from the total item.
 to convet array to Set you have to do

```
Set<Integer> uniqueItem = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(items));
int total_repeated_item=items.length-uniqueItem.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a unique ID to differentiate between items in you inventory, you can then put that in a Map which can just take care of counting duplicates for you . In your case the name of the item can be the unique identifier (Which would be the key in the Map)
.